# iOS: Section overlaps UITableView record

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to display three sections (@"Accounts and Tasks", @"Life Events", @"More") and relevant content in an UITableView. I am creating a custom UILabel for each row and try to display text.

Here is my code below. My issue is, The third section instead of displaying third section contents "Social Media", @"About Hop, @"Settings”, it is showing some first section contents and overlapping the text.

Could someone guide me to solve this please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"My Accounts",@"Transfers/Deposit",@"Pay Bills", @"Investment Center",@"Claims Center",@"Locators",@"Loan Calculator", nil];
    NSArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Auto Circle",@"Home Circle",nil];
    NSArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Social Media",@"About Hop", @"Settings", nil];


    self.keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Accounts and Tasks", @"Life Events", @"More", nil];
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arrTemp1, arrTemp2, arrTemp3, nil];

    self.tableContents = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

    NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
    NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [self.keys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.keys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [listData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"listData: %@", listData);

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 4, 250, 30)];

        label.text = [listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    }
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingsMore"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: set label.text outside the if block just before returning cell in celForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
     UILabel *label;
    if(cell == nil) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 4, 250, 30)];

        label.tag = 8888;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
    label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8888];
    label.text = [listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

If you set `label.text` in `if(cell == nil)`, the text will not get updated on reusing the cell.

Comment: I added this, tableview row shows all empty label text.

Comment: This is solving the issue. Thanks!